# i have a problem with installing fontawesome library in scene builder

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder

i have all jars of font awesome and i add them to scene builder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E15wq.png

but when i add them , most of them show me 0 item like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3XMX.png

so i am not getting the icons i need and i've been browsing for an answer for an hour and i didn't find the problem where is it !!!

Answer (score 0):

try to download scene builder gluon with java version 8 not 11.0 
this is the link : https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/